# How to not hide scroll bars in webview

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview

I am using WebView on OS X. How can I prevent the scroll bars from hiding automatically? Currently, the scroll bars disappear after some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebView is not responsible for showing/Hiding the scroll bars. It is the scrollview in which webView is embedded which contains scroller.

The hiding and showing of scroller is controlled by the System Preference -> General -> Show scroll bar setting.

If you want to always show the scroll bars for horizontal and vertical. You need to inherit the NSScroller and set the scroll style to legacy from preferredScrollerStyle method as shown below.

Then change the class of horizontal and vertical scroll bars from 'NSScroller' to 'InheritedScoller'

```
@interface InheritedScoller : NSScroller    
@end

@implementation InheritedScoller    
+(NSScrollerStyle) preferredScrollerStyle
{
    return NSScrollerStyleLegacy;
}
@end
```

Comment: Note that overriding the user's preference (as set in System Preferences -> General) is generally a bad thing to do. If the user prefers dynamically hidden scroll bars, you should respect that preference as much as possible.